# How do I rewrite my dynamic urls's to static without a folder extension?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, dynamic, url-rewriting

I need to get this URL /index.php?side=forside to look like this /forside/ and still get the contents from my includes folder to my index page.

How can I do this with an .htaccess file?
I already read a lot of other questions and answers on the topic, but they don't work or the change my URL to ex. /side/forside or /side/forside.html and that is not what I want...

I have tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index/side/(.*)/ index.php?side=$1
```

But when I remove the index/side/ it doesn't work?

Comment: please add the code that you tried so far

Comment: Take a look at this question. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: [Another SIte](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html) Look at this one as well

Comment: Sorry Jay and thanx oharkins

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one *side* you have, it seems logical to use:

```
RewriteRule ^forside/ index.php?side=forside
```

If you have a lot of sides; you could use:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)side/ index.php?side=$1
```

Comment: Please let me know if this works, post a comment explaining any issues or tag my reply as a proper answer